# Datatables search doesn't work on specific column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table where 90% of the information is being put in through the model.  One column I am putting in goes through `jQuery.getJSON`.

For that column I cannot search, I can type in something into the search field for `DataTables` for every other column and it will work.

```
<table>
     <tr>
          <th>Model Field</th>
          <th>getJSON Column</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td>@item.IWorkJustFine</td>
          <td><script type="text/javascript"> GetCompsForClaim(@item.myID)</script></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

This loads up a perfectly fine `jquery Datatable` with 0 errors.  The columns are all displaying the way they should.  When I type into the `Datatables` search box if it shows up in the `Model Field` it works.  When I try and search for something in the `getJSON field` it won't find it.

I have to assume it's something with how the column is being populated through the `getJSON`.

There are no restrictions for initializing the table.

```
jQuery('#table').dataTable({
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 25, 50, 100], [5, 10, 25, 50, 100]],
            "oLanguage": {
                "sSearch": "Search For Dealer:",
            }
        });
```

Here is the code used to fill the getJSON column.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetCompsForClaim(claimNo) {
        jQuery.getJSON('/AgentReport/GetComps/', { claimNo: claimNo }, null).done(function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    jQuery('#compList_' + claimNo).append(data[i]["desc"] + ' - ' + data[i]["part"] + '<br />');
                }
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

Why won't `Datatables` recognize this column as having data in it?

Comment: You are bypassing the plugin internal data cache by adding your own html. Plugin doesn't search live html, it has both cached html and cached data internally for much faster performance. Would be better if you updated the data through plugin api and use `draw()` to render your updates

Comment: Is there a way to bypass this?  I didn't think it would create the table until the page loaded (I have it in the on jQuery page load). @charlietfl

Comment: Depends when you intiailize the plugin. If it was initialized after you append the html (inside getJSON callback) would probably work.

Comment: @charlietfl I put the script to append the html at the top of the page not within a jquery page load event.  At the bottom of the page inside a jquery page load event i initialize the table.  I thought that would make it work, but for some reason I still can't search against the column.

Comment: but ajax is asynchronous, so the plugin is probably being initialized before the request has completed. Is the rest of the html being generated by server code? Why can't you make the query in your backend controller and merge the data there?

Comment: You're using a mixture of server-side and client-side datasources and expecting the client-side search feature to work. As @charlietfl says, you should generate the table data in the server-side code & populate the table using an an ajax call.  This will mean your searching, filtering & paging will be handled by the server-side code (obviously a bit more work involved there).

Comment: @markpsmith yeah I moved everything to be generated to a model and pass that into the page.  It works now.